# Automatic bookmark organizer?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

Is there an automatic bookmark organizer for Chrome?

I'm looking for something that can take a few hundred bookmarks, auto-magically find some tags for them (e.g. maybe "MSDN", "Youtube", etc.) and just  put them in a folder.

I realize this is a *lot* easier said than done but I thought it's worth asking, just in case...

Comment: I'd like to say that while in 2012 this would have been almost impossible, it's almost trivial today with natural language processing. I'm surprised it's not a feature in every browser.

Answer (score 1):

However I have not tested it myself but as they are saying that do the same waht you want. [Favorite and bookmark manager](http://www.outertech.com/en/bookmarks-favorites) tool seems to do your work. [Portable bookmark](http://www.resortlabs.com/bookmark-organizer/portable-bookmarks.php) may be helpful for you. Also see the [Google support](http://googlesystem.blogspot.in/2008/11/google-chrome-to-improve-bookmark.html).

Comment: +1 since it seems like they do what I want, but unfortunately they don't seem to be free...

Comment: My bad I couldn't find a freeware.

Comment: Haha no worries, it was my fault for forgetting to mention I wanted something free. :) Thanks anyway!

Comment: They have a lite version too check it if it meets to your any recommendations.